# Why is brunch not adding javascript from sub directories of /app?

Tags: brunch

I have a brunch config.coffee file located at `~/lens/v` that includes these lines:

```
  files:
    javascripts:
      defaultExtension: 'coffee'
      joinTo:
        'javascripts/app.js': /^app/
```

Brunch takes files with a .js extension that are located in the root of the /app directory and concatenates them into app.js -- but it does not concatenate files that are located in /app's sub directories.

Specifically, I am trying to get brunch to add in a coffeescript file located at `~/lens/v/app/assets`

```
~/lens/v/app/assets$ cat r.coffee 
d3.select("body").style("background-color", "black");
```

I am able to build the project like this

```
~/lens/v$brunch b
```

But when I search the app.js file for "d3" I can't find it. The JS is not getting concatenated for some reason.

```
grep -r "d3" app.js //returns nothing
```

This line from the config file `javascripts/app.js': /^app/` should join any javascript file in /app to app.js. But this is not happening. I get the same behavior when I change the extension of my javascript file to .js (from .coffee).

What steps can I take to debug this?

Comment: It seems that you don't have coffee-script plugin installed. See here: https://github.com/brunch/coffee-script-brunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Brunch has special handling for assets. They are treated differently from the files you wish to compile - copied as-is into your public directory.

The simplest way to solve the issue you're describing would be to move that coffeescript somewhere else under `app`, but not in `assets`.

Alternately, you could reconfigure what is treated as an asset in your brunch config under `conventions.assets`. https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/stable/docs/config.md#conventions

Answer (score 0):

I asked this exact same question a few days ago, and answered it here:

[How can I compile individual CoffeeScript files in the assets directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316338/how-can-i-compile-individual-coffeescript-files-in-the-assets-directory)

*If* you want to keep those files in assets/, my solution is to use the After-Brunch plugin and convert them manually, as I show in the link above.

Otherwise, move them out of assets/, and use the coffeescript plugin in I linked to first.